# Understanding the recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

Maybe this function is very simple for you. but i have problems with how this functions works.please explain how to compile this function.

It is zero the count in the run loop ?

```js
function countChars(elm) {
  var i, count = 0;

  if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
    return elm.nodeValue.length;
  }

  for (i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    count += countChars(child);
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Put a few console.log s inbetween, add some breakpoints in the debugger, take a simple example, run it, and see that it isnt really complicated.

Comment: Just translate it into words: if the current node is a text node, return its length, otherwise - loop over its child and call the function again (for every child) and sum the result. Return the result.

Comment: It counts the combined length of all the text stored in the tree's *leaf* nodes

Comment: The function will recursively call its self until it reaches a TEXT_NODE. 

But the for loop is not testing for var i value, and so will never exit. (var i will increment indefinitely).

If you change the for loop to:-

`for ( var i = 0;  i < elm.childNodes.lenfth; i++ ) { var child = elm.childNodes[i].....  }`

you may have more luck.

Comment: @Jonasw I did, but still did not get the result.

Comment: @user3094755 no, the loop should work properly.

Comment: I fully understand how much this function repeats and what it does. My question is thatEvery time the loop is executed, the count is zeroed? And if so, how is the sum returned?

Comment: @AlonEitan no this worked Absolutely true. The function runs perfectly and works. But I do not understand this function.

Comment: @miladasghari That's good to know. Please check the answers below and see if it helps (They are both good answers), you can upvote/accept if you think they are helpful

Comment: `count` is a local variable in the function instance, meaning every instance of the function has its own unique, private variable. It's not one single variable that gets zeroed every time the function runs. A new variable is created with the value `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Some Text
```

The DOM will look like this:

```
[
Textnode {"Some Text"}
]
```

The upper code is valid HTML, actually it is a text node. So if we want to get its length we simply take its length:

```
if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
   return elm.nodeValue.length;
}
```

Lets imagine a more complicated case:

```
Some Text <span> nested </span>
```

DOM:

```
[
Textnode {"Some Text"},
Span { 
  children:[
    Textnode {"nested"}
  ]
 }
]
```

Now weve got four nodes. A text node and a span node, and a text node nested in the span node. And theyre all nested in some kind of body. So to get its text length, we need to iterate over the nodes, and then go deeper ( have a look into *tree traversal* ):

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {
  count += countChars(child);
}
return count;
```

So the upper example will work like this:

```
count=0
iterate over body:
  child textnode:
      count+="Some Text".length
  child span:
      inner count=0
      iterate over span:
          child textnode
               inner count+="nested".length
     count+=inner count
finished
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
** This function counts the characters of a given node.
**
** @param : The current node to work on
**/
function countChars(elm) {

  // Set local variables
  var i, count = 0;

  // Check to see if the current node is text.
  // If its a text it cannot have any other children so simply
  // return the text length int his node
  if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
    return elm.nodeValue.length;
  }

  // This is not a text node so driil doen in to its all
  // children and loop into them to count the number of 
  // character they have
  for (i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    // dive into the current child in count the number of 
    // characters it contains. since we use recursion the count will 
    // be returned form the previous run and will return the number of
    // characters collect from all "previous" children

    count += countChars(child);
  }

  return count;
}
```

---

[image]